# Symfony2 - Doctrine and FOSUserBundle - wrong annotations

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine, fosuserbundle

I am new to Symfony2 in general. This issue relates to Doctrine and FOSUserBundle though.

I have the following User.php Entity created based on FOSUserBundle and a self-referencing many-to many.

```
<?php

namespace Pan100\MoodLogBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

    /**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;


/**
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="hasAccessToMe")
 **/
protected $hasAccessTo;

/**
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="hasAccessTo")
 * @JoinTable(name="access",
 *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="accessor_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 **/
private $hasAccessToMe;    

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
        $this->hasAccessTo = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->hasAccessToMe = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
}
```

Gives me the following error when attempting to update cache or drop:

```
[Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException]                           
[Semantical Error] The annotation "@ManyToMany" in property Pan100\MoodLog  
Bundle\Entity\User::$hasAccessTo was never imported. Did you maybe forget   
to add a "use" statement for this annotation?
```

What is wrong here? And what is a "use statement"?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You forgot to add the `@ORM\` prefix in your annotations:

```
/**
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="hasAccessToMe")
 **/
```

should be

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="hasAccessToMe")
 **/
```

Comment: success! since I use it as ORM I have to put ORM\ in front of all the annotations.

Answer (score 3):

You could also import each annotation individually — the way I prefer:

```php
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ManyToMany;
// ...

/**
 * @Entity
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Thing")
     */
    private $things;

    // ...
}
```