# Semantical error The annotation in property does not exist or could not be loaded

Tags: orm, zend-framework2, doctrine

When running orm:schem-tool:update, I get this error:

```
[Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException]


[Semantical Error] The annotation "@Doctrine\Orm\Mapping\ManyToMany" in property Admin\Entity\AppointmentDefinition::$products does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.
```

I've been searching already all over Stackoverflow for why this happens but I haven't found anything yet. It seems to work for @ORM\OneToMany or @ORM\ManyToOne annotations. I also get the same error for @ORM\JoinTable.

Here is my entity class:

```
namespace Admin\Entity;

use Doctrine\Orm\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection as ArrayCollection;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="appointment_definition")
 */
class AppointmentDefinition
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     * 
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer");
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $timeLength;

    /**
     * @var string
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=200, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @var object ArrayCollection
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Admin\Entity\Product")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="appointment_definition_product",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\@JoinColumn(name="appointment_definition_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\@JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    protected $products;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
     * @ORM\Column(name="updated_at", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="deleted_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $deletedAt;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->products = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Get timelength
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getTimeLength()
    {
        return $this->timeLength;
    }

    /**
     * Set timelength
     *
     * @param int $timeLength
     * @return self
     */
    public function setTimeLength($timeLength)
    {
        $this->timeLength = $timeLength;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get appointment definition name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set appointment definition name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return self
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get createdAt
     *
     * @return datetime
     */
    public function getCreatedAt()
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    /**
     * Get updatedAt
     *
     * @return datetime
     */
    public function getUpdatedAt()
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    /**
     * Get deletedAt
     *
     * @return datetime
     */
    public function getDeletedAt()
    {
        return $this->deletedAt;
    }

    /**
     * Set deletedAt
     *
     * @param integer $deletedAt
     * @return self
     */
    public function setDeletedAt($deletedAt)
    {
        $this->deletedAt = $deletedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get products
     *
     * @return object ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getProducts()
    {
        return $this->products;
    }

    /**
     * Add products
     *
     * @param array|ArrayCollection $products
     * @return self
     */
    public function addProducts($products)
    {
        foreach($products as $product) {
            $this->addProduct($product);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add product
     *
     * @param object $product
     * @return self
     */
    public function addProduct(Product $product)
    {
        $this->products->add($product);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove product
     *
     * @param object $product
     * @return self
     */
    public function removeProduct(Product $product)
    {
        $this->products->removeElement($product);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove products
     *
     * @param array|ArrayCollection $products
     * @return self
     */
    public function removeProducts($products)
    {
        $this->products->removeProduct($products);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Can someone please point what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: After a couple more hours of searching I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15071378/6367598). It works but it just seems odd that some annotations work with "@ORM" while others I have to import individually. I hope this will help others that encounter this problem and maybe somebody can figure out why this happens.

Comment: Wait, I just found out that `use Doctrine\Orm\Mapping as ORM;` should be `use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;`. This was causing the error. Got to have to be more careful with Doctrines case sensitivity.